# Debian: How to revert back to KDE after switching to GNOME?

Tags: debian, gnome, kde, window-manager

MY machine is running Debian 8 "Jessie".
I installed Gnome desktop environment by

> sudo apt-get install gnome

now every time my machine is switched on I'm presented with Gnome desktop environment whereas **I want to go back to KDE** (login screen doesn't let me change).

How to fix this?

I tried with **sudo  update-alternatives --config x-window-manager** but apparently the windows manager is just a part of the whole GUI system.

Comment: Your display manager should let you choose. What display manager are you using? `kdm` (which I use) certainly let's you choose.

Comment: yes kdm and lightdm let you choose but not Gnome apparently. I had to install lightdm to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that your display manager doesn't let you choose, but I don't like neither Gnome nor KDE, so I don't know what you'll be running, but you can try some others. Personally I like lightdm, but there's a list at 
https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager

A less subtle approach would be to uninstall gnome.

Comment: apparently I couldn't choose a different workspace from Gnome login screen but installing lightdm and switching to KDE did the trick.